# How do you get the size of a qtreewidget column?

Tags: qt

I wanted to resize columns to contents, but unfortunately the first column, where I have labels with text, gets overlapped by the second column, maybe qt miscalculated something, so I wanted to get the size of the first column (SIZE) and resize it manually to SIZE + some_small_constant. So how do I get the size of a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the tree view's header via the [`headerItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#headerItem) property of `QTreeWidget`, then use `sizeHint` and `setSizeHint` of [`QTreeWidgetItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html) to get/set the size of any given column.